# Computer not choosing a new value on the reiteration of a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm been trying to write a simple game of rock paper scissors and I'm stuck at trying to get the game to run for 5 rounds. The computer chooses a value from an array at random but then it doesn't choose a new one on the reiteration of the loop. As an example case, the computer chooses rock for round 1 and then doesn't choose anything different for the next 4 rounds. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
let myArray = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
let randomValue = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]

function computerPlay() {
    return randomValue;
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playerSelection == computerSelection) {
        console.log('It\'s a tie!')
        return
    }   else if ((playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'scissors') || 
                 (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'rock') || 
                 (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'paper')) {
        console.log('The human wins!');
        console.log(playerScore += 1);
        return
    }   else {
        console.log('The computer wins!');
        console.log(computerScore += 1);
        return
    }
}

let playerScore = parseInt(0);
let computerScore = parseInt(0);
function game(){
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    let playerSelection = prompt('Choose your weapon');
    const computerSelection = computerPlay();
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
    console.log('Your score = ' + playerScore);
    console.log('Computer\'s score = ' + computerScore);
}
}

console.log(game())
```

Comment: You create a random value at the beginning of the code and never create a new random value. If you want `computerPlay()` to return a random value each time it needs to create a new random value in `computerPlay()` (or in something `computerPlay()` calls).

Comment: Simply move the `let randomValue` statement into the `computerPlay()` function.

Comment: I put in "water" but the computer always won :) - just to point out a validation fun point.

Comment: Also putting the `+=1` in the console logs causes a bit of a challenge for those who like instant gratification

Comment: See what I was thinking was that if you put in something other than a plausible answer i.e. (rock, paper or scissors) you were essentially forfeiting the round. I suppose I could change that though! Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move randomValue's definition to inside the computerPlay() function because every time computerPlay() is called, it is not generating a new value, but returning the pre-defined value calculated at the beginning of the program for randomValue. If you move it, then randomValue will be calculated and defined every time computerPlay() is called.

I recommend doing this instead:

```
let myArray = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

function computerPlay() {
    let randomValue = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)]
    return randomValue;
}

{insert rest of code}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The visual is really helpful and cleared that up for me. Now next time I'll know to check for this! :D

Comment: Why not make it the accepted answer? ;)